# Longer story like "Toy Shop" by Harry Harrison

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I just read the short story “Toy Shop” by Henry Maxwell Dempsey aka Harry Harrison. An inventor sells a toy space ship that can fly - by means of some cleverly hidden wires, plus some unexplainable effect that reduces its weight just enough so that the wires can lift it. The mechanism is patented but unexplained.

That’s all. I think I can remember a much longer but still short story where this is just one of several inventions. Like a marble on a wire that passes through a thin metal wall, a game of luck where some people never win and some win most of the time without explanation and other toys.

Can anyone identify the longer story, and knows where it might be published?

Comment: FWIW, Toy Shop came up [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74093/short-story-involving-a-toy-saucer-with-fake-antigravity/74099#74099)

Comment: It is probably the same story asked about in [Physicist finds new laws of physics, patents toys](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66349/physicist-finds-new-laws-of-physics-patents-toys), but the only answer to that also suggests _Toy Story_.

Comment: Oh wait, that was you as well so this is a repost of your 2014 question.